# In the search box display the country flag only when the country gets selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I'm working on a custom dropdown, to select a country. These are my requirements:

**Requirement 1:** Typing a letter should automatically populate a dropdown list with countries whose name starts with that letter.

**Requirement 2:** When I click on a country in the dropdown, it should be classified as *active*.

**Requirement 3:** The flag of the country should be displayed on the right side of the search box.

Currently, I have completed auto-population part and it is working properly. I need help with the other stuff

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "list");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```css
.container {
    width: 60%;
   
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #484848;
    border-radius: 6px;    
    
}
.container input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.list{
    
    border-top: 2px solid #777;
}
.list div {
    
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
.list > div:hover{
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
/*    border-radius: 3px;*/
}
.cunt-flg {
    background: transparent;
    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
}
.cunt-flg img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
/*    flex: 1;*/
    flex-shrink: 3;
}
.cunt-flg-img1{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
}
.cunt-flg-img {
    margin-left: 130px;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: #bdbdbd !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
            
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10"><input id="myInput"  name="myCountry" type="text" placeholder="Search Country..." /> </div>
                    <div class="col-2 cunt-flg" align="" style="display: block">
                        <img src="Australia.png" class="cunt-flg-img" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
           
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or some other frontend library? You should probably include the link for that in the snippet if you are. Otherwise we won't be able to see your the output of your code the way you see it on your computer

Comment: I am using bootstrap

Comment: more I am using png images for flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included it in my snippet. To get the code to work, you can toggle the `display` property of the image. So when the input gets a valid input, show the display the image, otherwise keep it hidden.

To do this, add a class *hide* to your image container:

```
<div class="col-2 cunt-flg hide" align="">
  <img src="Australia.png" class="cunt-flg-img" >
</div>
```

And give this class the following property:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Use javascript to toggle.

```
let image = document.querySelector('.cunt-flg')

// Inside the input eventListener handler

// If there is nothing in the input, hide the flag again
if (!val) { image.classList.add('hide'); return false;} 

// Show the image when there is a valid input (after the list closes)
image.classList.remove('hide')
```

Here's how it looks:

```js
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
  var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var a, b, i, val = this.value;
      let image = document.querySelector('.cunt-flg')
      /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
      closeAllLists();
      if (!val) { image.classList.add('hide'); return false;}
      currentFocus = -1;
      /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      a.setAttribute("class", "list");
      /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
      this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
      /*for each item in the array...*/
      for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
        if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
          /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
          b = document.createElement("DIV");
          /*make the matching letters bold:*/
          b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
          b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
          /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
          b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
          /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
          b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
              /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
              inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
              image.classList.remove('hide')
              /*close the list of autocompleted values,
              (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
              closeAllLists();
          });
          a.appendChild(b);
        }
      }
  });
  /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
  inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
      if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
        increase the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus++;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
        /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
        decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
        currentFocus--;
        /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
        addActive(x);
      } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
        e.preventDefault();
        if (currentFocus > -1) {
          /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
          if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
        }
      }
  });
  function addActive(x) {
    /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
    if (!x) return false;
    /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
    removeActive(x);
    if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
    if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
    /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
    x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
  }
  function removeActive(x) {
    /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
    }
  }
  function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
    /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
    except the one passed as an argument:*/
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      }
    }
    
  }
  /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
  document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      closeAllLists(e.target);
  });
}

/*An array containing all the country names in the world:*/
var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];

/*initiate the autocomplete function on the "myInput" element, and pass along the countries array as possible autocomplete values:*/
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

```css
.container {
    width: 60%;
   
    margin: 100px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #484848;
    border-radius: 6px;    
    
}
.container input {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
.list{
    
    border-top: 2px solid #777;
}
.list div {
    
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
.list > div:hover{
    background-color: #bdbdbd;
/*    border-radius: 3px;*/
}
.cunt-flg {
    background: transparent;
    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
}
.cunt-flg img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
/*    flex: 1;*/
    flex-shrink: 3;
}
.cunt-flg-img{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
}

.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}

/*when hovering an item:*/
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
/*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
.autocomplete-active {
  background-color: #bdbdbd !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
            
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-10"><input id="myInput"  name="myCountry" type="text" placeholder="Search Country..." /> </div>
                    <div class="col-2 cunt-flg hide" align="">
                        <img src="Australia.png" class="cunt-flg-img" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
           
        </div>
```

**Edit:**

Changing the flag for each country depends on how your flags are named and where they're located. Make sure you're using the same file type for all flags (.png/.jpeg etc), and have a single naming convention. For example, each flag should have a name like *countryName.png*.

Then in the `<img>` tag, insert the name of the country into the src string using JS like this:

```
const img = document.querySelector('.cunt-flg-img')
img.src = val + ".png"

// Or if the images are in another folder
img.src = "folder-name/" + val + ".png"
```

Comment: this is working, but can you guide me to what if I have all country flags. And that would be parallel the country on the respective country flag will get the display.